# pdftk: Compressing a bunch of PDFs en masse/in batch while keeping the filenames?

Tags: linux, pdf, batch, compression, pdftk

I have a rather simple problem.  I have a lot of PDFs that I want to compress, all grouped by college class.  I don't have the time or energy to manually run the compress command when I know I can automate the whole thing.

However, I don't want to change the names of the files; how can I use pdftk compress an entire folder's PDFs and place the compressed versions in another folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in linux you can simply use these few lines of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir compressed
for f in *.pdf; do pdftk $f output compressed/$f compress; done
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks!  (Also, a quick Google tells me that for files with spaces, surround $f in quotes.)

Comment: This does not compress. Just moves the file.